# C# Make sure that interface implementation inherits from a particular base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, extension-methods

I have an interface

```
public interface IInputReciever {
    void OnRecieveInput(InputInfo Info);
}
```

and an interface extension class

```
public static class IInputRecieverExtensions {
    public static void SubscribeToInput(this IInputReciever Reciever) { 
       //Use member of X
    }
    public static void UnsubscribeFromInput(this IInputReciever Reciever) {
       //Use member of X
    }
}
```

Let's say I have two classes A and B; however, while only B inherits from X, both implement my interface.

```
public class B : X, IInputReciever {
   //Contains members of B and X
}

public class A : IInputReciever {
   //Contains members of A only
}
```

In my interface extension I'd like to use the memebers of X, but that will not compile because the implementor is not known to be a subclass of X and also is not guaranteed to be one.

**Can I somehow force my implementors to derive from X in order for this scenario to work - or is there a better way for solving this?**

Comment: so you're trying to do something like `var b= new B(); b.SubsribeToInput();` but it's not working?

Comment: have you used generic constraints?

Comment: If you need `X`, why aren't you using type X instead of the interface? If you want the extension to work on some LINQ statement you can use the `OfType<>()` extension to ensure that you only process objects of the correct type

Comment: @DLeh Well, yes the code runs - right now. But I do not have any content in SubsribeToInput(); if I use b.InstanceId (which is a member of X) it would not compile because IInputReciever is not guaranteed to be an X or derive from it.

Comment: Sure, if you want to ensure an implementation rather than an interface, avoid the interface and use type `X` everywhere. You can add abstract members that'll replace members currently available in your interface and not in `X`

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - having problem X, thinking the answer is Y and asking about Y instead of X when problems occur. *Why* do you want to use an incompatible interface when the implementation requires a specific type? How do you want to use this method?

Comment: I agree, I was about to say that if my design required this level of constraints to solve, I'd probably start to rethink it.

Comment: I think there are several applications where this is the right way. `X` could be a `InputReceiverExtensable`. In that case, it could carry the extended methods, but to be able to implement them in there, it'd must be an abstract class. So you get problems with other stuff maybe, since you only need extensions here. Think of handling stuff like protocol-families.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos X is provided by a framework I use and my class needs to derive from it. And just a few derivers from X actualy use the IInputReciever (f.e. in 10000 instances I might have 20 that use it) It has to be an interface that I can implement. The problem is that the interface extensions require the InstanceId provided by the framework.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Although, now when I think about it. Not all implementor of IInputReciever have access to the extension methods. Damn, I am going to read through the keywords provided in the comments and see if I can find a better design. However, the answer to this question has been posted. Thank you ver much for your ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic method. Thus, you can work with `where`.

```
public static void SubscribeToInput<TInputReciever>(this TInputReciever Reciever) where TInputReciever : IInputReciever, X
{ 
   //Use member of X
}
```

This will force a Receiver to implement `IInputReceiver` and `X`, because of the constraints of the generic type arguments.

Comment: @dcastro there aren't multiple types here, there is one type and one interface

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And `X`.

Comment: This is indeed awesome! Not having to use T is great :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

The point of using an interface is to indicate that you don't care about the implementation details, that is, what class implements the interface.  If you must force the derived classes to use a particular implementation, then make X an abstract base class, don't provide an interface, and make your extension method reference X instead of the interface.

Comment: That would be the easier route - yes. But B absolutely needs to derive from X and not all derivers from X need to implement IInputReciever

Comment: Yes, you loose some flexibility. The question is not about to force all classes, which derive from `IInputReceiver` to also derive from `X`, but to make the extensions work only with `IInputReceiver`s which also are `X`. Big difference.

Comment: @NoelWidmer why? What is the *real* problem? I bet there is a far easier solution once you describe the real problem, instead of asking how to break out of the type system.

Comment: create an abstract class Y (BaseReceiver) that inherits X and implements IInputReceiver and use it as a type instead of IInputReceiver where you want to force inheritance of X and implementation of IInputReceiver.

Comment: @Andrew Possible solution - not a comment but another good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use generic extension method with constraints:

```
public static class IInputRecieverExtensions{
    public static void SubscribeToInput<T>(this T Reciever) where T : X, IInputReceiver { 
        //Use member of X
    }
    public static void UnsubscribeFromInput<T>(this T Reciever) where T : X, IInputReceiver {
        //Use member of X
    }
}
```